# WPF DataGrid - assign DefaultValue to ComboBoxColumn upon creating new row

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid, default-value

My `DataGrid` is bound to an `ObservableCollection` in my `ViewModel`.

I add new rows via a command that looks like this:

```
public void AddItem() {
    MyObservableCollection.Add(new MyClass());
}
```

How can I set default value for a `DataGridComboBoxColumn` in my `DataGrid` when I create new rows, because as is - it turns up empty, which mess up my bindings. The initial X-number of rows upon loading has values, just not new rows that the user add.
If I could, for example, bind the `DefaultValue` to whichever item is at index 1 in the `ComboBoxColumn`, that'd be great.
Is that possible?

The XAML for the DataGrid and the DataGridComboBoxColumn looks like this:

```
<DataGrid
    AutoGenerateColumns="False"
    ItemsSource="{Binding MyObservableCollection}">

     <DataGridComboBoxColumn
         ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource MyObservableCollection}}"
         SelectedValueBinding="{Binding PropertyName1}"
         DisplayMemberPath="PropertyName1"
         SelectedValuePath="PropertyName1" />

</DataGrid>
```

**What I have tried:**

I tried setting the `TargetNullValue` and `FallBackValue`, just to get a value to appear, because that's all I need. But it does not work. I also tried setting the `DefaultValue` when instantiating the new row, but I couldn't get it to work.
Something like this added to my `AddItem()` method:

```
MyObservableCollection.Add(new MyClass());
DataTable dt = new();
dt.Columns.Add("PropertyName1", typeof(string));
dt.Columns["PropertyName1"].DefaultValue = /* not sure what to put here */ ;
```

I tried adding some random text there, and it does not show up, so something's off...

Answer (score 1):

You must bind the `SelectedItem` of the `ComboBox` or `DataGridComboBoxColumn.SelecetedItemBinding` to be precise.
Assuming that such a `SelectedMyClass` property would be defined in the current `DataGrid.DataContext` the binding could look as followed:

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Value"
                        ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource MyObservableCollection}}"
                        DisplayMemberPath="PropertyName1"
                        SelectedItemBinding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}, Path=DataContext.SelectedMyClassItem}" />
```

But note that this would lead to a have each row bind to the same value. This is very likely not what you want.

---

Usually the items source of the cell's `ComboBox` is a collection defined on the data model itself - in your case `MyClass`. In this scenario the `SelectedItem` property (binding source of `ComboBox.SelectedItem`) would also be defined on the  `MyClass` data model. I renamed `MyClass` to `DataGridItem` to make the purpose of the participating models more clear). The `SelectedItem` is essential when you want to display an nitial value in the `ComboBox` cell:

```
// The item model defines the source collection for the cell's ComboBox
class DataGridItem
{
  public ObservableCollection<DataItem> DataItems { get; }
  
  // TODO::Property must raise INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged
  public DataItem SelectedDataItem { get; set; }

  public string SomeProperty { get; set; }
}
```

Simply initialize the `DataGridItem.SelectedDataItem` to show an initial value in the `ComboBox` cell:

```
public void AddItem() 
{
  var newDataGridItem = new DataGridItem();
  newDataGridItem.SelectedDataItem = newDataGridItem.DataItems.FirstOrDefault();  
  this.DataGridItems.Add(newDataGridItem);
}
```

Then adjust the data binding on the `DataGridComboBoxColumn`. Since the definition of the `DataGridComboBoxColumn` is not part of the visual tree the `DataContext` is not the data model of the current row. So we must setup the binding of the `ComboBox.ItemsSource` using a `Style`:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding DataGridItems}">
  <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Value"
                          DisplayMemberPath="SomeProperty"
                          SelectedItemBinding="{Binding SelectedDataItem}">
    <DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
      <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
        <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding DataItems}" />
      </Style>
    </DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>

    <DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
      <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
        <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding DataItems}" />
      </Style>
    </DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
  </DataGridComboBoxColumn>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: thank you very much for an informative post. I am working to implement your solution, but - my ObservableCollection is in my ViewModel. How could I work-around that? There is automatic coupling between my View and ViewModel, and I would rather not change that.

Comment: This is not a problem. My example already assumes the `MyObservableCollection` (or DataGridItems) is a ObservableCollection defined in you view model. You bind this collection to the DataGrid like you already did in your original post. Then each item model in the DataGrid.ItemsSource should als have a collection and a SelectedItem property which both bind to the actual DataGridComboBoxColumn (the cell) - this is the second part of the answer..

Comment: thanks for elaborating. I now get a System.ArgumentNullException: 'Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'source')' when I tried adding a new row. I have triple checked, and I believe I set everything up as you instructed. Hmmm..
I got the exception at the 2nd line in the AddItem() method.
Also, X number of rows are initialized when the form is loaded, they used to have one row for each instance of SomeProperty, but now they all share the same index of SomeProperty, and, when I change one of them, they all change.

Comment: First of all I only showed a minimal code version to display the pattern. You would of course have to initialize the DataItems collection in the constructor of `DataGridItem`, otherwise when you reference it to add or get items thze collection will be `null`.

Comment: Regarding your sencond issue: `SomeProperty` is a string property of `DataGridItem`. If you follow my example, you would have a row for each `DataGridItem` instance inside the `DataGridItems` collection, when `DataGridItems` collection binds to `DataGrid.ItemsSource`. If you have column autogeneration enabled, then SomeProperty would be a column. If you, like you said, change one cell value and this results in changing all row's cell values too, then you used the same instance for every row. Make sure not to add the same instance multiple times to the `DataGridItems` collection.

Comment: If this doesn't help then please update your question and add the current implementation so that I can review what you have done. You should understand that `DataGridItems` is a ObservableCollection in the same view model class like the AddItem method. the example does also not show how to initialize each `DataGridItem`. Apart from the afore mentioned constructor to initialize the `DataItems` collection, you would also have to add the items to this colection in order to be displayed by the ComboBox.